# python random.randint() did not return any value

Tags: python-2.7, random

I need to append random hours to date field. For this I used following code:

```
datetime.utcnow().date() + relativedelta(hours=random.randint(0,23))
```

This returned response:

```
datetime.date(2018, 7, 5)
```

Above response is not reproducible. Wondering if using random.randint() is reliable. Please let me know what caused this to occur or what other solution I can use for this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't just return 0?

Comment: Actually, wait, why are you trying to add hours to a date?

Comment: I want to randomise some entries for scheduling purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens exactly when `random.randint(0,23)` returns `0`. In that case, you get a final result of type `datetime.date` instead of `datetime.datetime`, because the delta is basically zero. So `random.randint()` *is* reliable, but sometimes it does return `0`, as expected.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your response.